# Array from tabpages to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-ce

I'm still struggling with a WinCE app.
I have an xml file which loads perfectly on Form_Load. The data pulls through to fields in tabpages, where I run a foreach loop in order to display the information.

However, now that I want to save it to a new xml file, i can't seem to write the data to file.

Help please!

The xml file looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <AssessmentForm title="MACHINE-NAME Assessment">
    <Title>MACHINE-NAME Assessment</Title>
    <AssessmentSections>
      <AssessmentSection sectionNameID="SECTION_ONE" sectionGroupID="0">
        <SectionName>SECTION_NUMBER_1</SectionName>
        <SectionDescription>Description of Section to go here</SectionDescription>
        <SectionItems>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_ONE" itemID="0" itemGroupID="0">
            <ItemName>Item One</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_TWO" itemID="1" itemGroupID="0">
            <ItemName>Item Two</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_THREE" itemID="2" itemGroupID="0">
            <ItemName>Item Three</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
        </SectionItems>
      </AssessmentSection>
      <AssessmentSection sectionNameID="SECTION_TWO" sectionGroupID="1">
        <SectionName>SECTION_NUMBER_2</SectionName>
        <SectionDescription>Description of Section to go here</SectionDescription>
        <SectionItems>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_ONE" itemID="0" itemGroupID="1">
            <ItemName>Item One</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_TWO" itemID="1" itemGroupID="1">
            <ItemName>Item Two</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_THREE" itemID="2" itemGroupID="1">
            <ItemName>Item Three</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
        </SectionItems>
      </AssessmentSection>
      <AssessmentSection sectionNameID="SECTION_THREE" sectionGroupID="2">
        <SectionName>SECTION_NUMBER_2</SectionName>
        <SectionDescription>Description of Section to go here</SectionDescription>
        <SectionItems>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_ONE" itemID="0" itemGroupID="2">
            <ItemName>Item One</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_TWO" itemID="1" itemGroupID="2">
            <ItemName>Item Two</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_THREE" itemID="2" itemGroupID="2">
            <ItemName>Item Three</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
        </SectionItems>
      </AssessmentSection>
    </AssessmentSections>
</AssessmentForm>
```

Comment: EDIT:

My current code to display the items in the xml file, are as follows:

foreach (var m in menu)
            {
                //display button array
            }
            foreach (var sectionItem in m.sectionItems.Where(x => x.itemGroupID == m.sectionID))
            {
                //display sub in textbox & combobox array
            }

I want to save the textbox & combobox to xml.

Comment: can you add your code for saving to the xml file?

Comment: My apologies.

`XDocument doc = new XDocument(
new XElement("Assessment",
new XElement("AssessmentDetails",
new XElement("SectionName", sections.sectionName),
new XElement("ItemName", items.itemName),
new XElement("Sections",
from i in items.itemName
select new XElement("Items",
new XElement("Item", txtbox.Text),
new XElement("Result", cbBox.Text)))));`